# Is there away to change the height of map view programmatically?

Tags: android

I'm having problem in getting the final layout look that I need for my app.

However, i'm thinking if I could change the the width of map programmatically it will solve the problem?

So i wonder if altering the height of map view programmatically is possible?

Comment: Do you mean "programmatically"?

Comment: if you mean programatically... just as you would change it to any other view.

Comment: Yes, programmatically. could you please explain how. I'm new to android programming.

Comment: To show a code example, would need to know what your parent is. Can you post your XML?

Comment: let's tidy up the site by closing very old dud questions like this